# Can I deploy a Vuejs app and Python backend app in the same Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, procfile

I have a decoupled application in which the frontend is in Vuejs (SPA) and the REST backend in Python/Django.

For cost reasons, I would like to deploy both of them in the same Heroku app. Is it possible?

I've been reading about the Procfile but I'm not sure it allow me achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just serve the static files from django.

For example, in your `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/',
    outputDir: "dist",
    assetsDir: "static",
    indexPath: "spa.html",
    css: {extract: false}

}
```

In django `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^app/*', TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name='spa.html',
        extra_context=SPA_CONTEXT,
    )),
]
```

And remember to add the static assets and template folders in your `settings.py`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very much possible.

I found some documented help by a simple google search. You can refer to these links -

- https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/gtalarico/django-vue-template
- https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/gtalarico/flask-vuejs-template